# Как преобразовать символ в арифметическую операцию?

Tags: java, char, калькулятор

Сгенерировал арифметическую операцию, но результат выдает неверный, потому что воcпринимает под `char` конкретное значение из юникода.

Как этот случайный `char` представить именно операцией (сложение, вычитание)?

```java
String str = "-+*";
int z = (int) (Math.random() * str.length());
char ch = str.charAt(z);
```

Если я попытаюсь посчитать, например, `int result = (x + ch + y)`, то в качестве `ch` будет взято число из таблицы юникода, а хотелось бы получить сгенерированный символ.

Comment: Т.е. если я попытаюсь посчитать, например, int resulr = (x + ch + y), то в качестве ch будет взято число из таблицы юникода, а хотелось бы получить сгенерированный символ.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `switch`

Comment: А что именно вы хотите получить в результате `x + ch + y`?  Какой смысл прибавлять символ `'+'` в этом выражении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Сгенерировал арифметическую операцию* -- не совсем так, был сгенерирован *символ* операции, полученный из строки.

Для *применения* некой операции к неким числам следует сопоставить значение символа с неким действием, например, при помощи `switch`:

- обычный оператор `switch`

```java
int result;
switch (ch) {
    case '+': result = x + y; break;
    case '-': result = x - y; break;
    case '*': result = x * y; break; 
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad operation: " + ch);
}
```

- `switch`-выражение (Java 14+):

```java
int result = switch (ch) {
    case '+' -> x + y;
    case '-' -> x - y;
    case '*' -> x * y; 
    default  -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad operation: " + ch);
};
```

---

Однако, в Java *можно* определить *операции*, используя функциональные интерфейсы, в данном случае может подойти [`IntBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html), принимающий два аргумента и возвращающий результат типа `int`, или же [`BiFunction<T1,T2,R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html), для которого можно дополнительно специфицировать типы аргументов и результата.

```java
IntBinaryOperator add = (a, b) -> a + b;
IntBinaryOperator sub = (a, b) -> a - b;
IntBinaryOperator mul = (a, b) -> a * b;

IntBinaryOperator[] ops = {sub, add, mul};

int x = 10;
int y = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    IntBinaryOperator op = ops[(int)(Math.random() * ops.length)];
    System.out.println("Random op of x and y = " + op.applyAsInt(x, y));
}
```

```
Random op of x and y = 200
Random op of x and y = -10
Random op of x and y = 30
Random op of x and y = 30
Random op of x and y = 200
```